# Не работает командная строка

Tags: cmd

Не работает командная строка при вводе любой стандартной команды, перечитал много форумов, ничего не помогает.
При вводе команды через "Выполнить" все работает,но консоль мгновенно закрывается...както так..

Comment: Лучше написать `cmd` и выполнять команды уже там.

Comment: Как именно не работает? Какой стандартной команды? Команды через Выполнить работать не должны, только программы.

Answer (score 1):

> При вводе команды через "Выполнить" все работает,но консоль мгновенно закрывается...

В этом случае команду нужно предварять запуском командного процессора без закрытия окна. Т.е. вместо

```
КомандаДляВыполнения
```

нужно выполнять

```
cmd /k КомандаДляВыполнения
```

Ну и совет, который дал **don Rumata**, ничем не хуже.

Ещё вариант - запустить явно окно командной строки (пуск - Все программы - Стандартные - Командная строка), и уже там давать свои команды.

> Не работает командная строка

Работает она. И даже результат даёт. Просто Вы не видите (или не успеваете увидеть) прогресса выполнения и выводимых сообщений.